# Is L a linear transformation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

[image]

I have to prove is L is a linear transformation on the field $P_3(R)$, if it is then I'd have to find the matrix of the linear transformation from the standard base vectors $p(1),p(x),p(x^2),p(x^3)$.

[image]

Now I'm a bit confused as it turns out, it goes from $P_3(R)->P_4(R)$ and how would I then find the matrix of the linear transformation? In general how does it look when I'm transforming something from a space of dimension N to a space of dimension M, so far I have only encountered the transformation from N->N so it's a bit confusing.

EDIT:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&4&0&0\\ 0&2&0&0\\ 0&3&1&0\\ 0&0&0&-2\\ 0&0&0&-5\end{pmatrix}$$ 
This would be the linear transformation matrix if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: A matrix mapping an $n$ dimensional space to an $m$ dimensional space is $m \times n$--$m$ rows, $n$ columns. Also, your notation is a bit sloppy: $L$ doesn't act on $p(1)$, it acts on the polynomial $p(x)=1$. Similarly $\mathbb{P}_3$ is a vector space, not a field. As for proving linearity, you don't need to furnish the matrix, you just need to prove $L(c_1 p +c_2 q)=c_1 L(p)+c_2 L(q)$ when $p,q$ are in $\mathbb{P}_3$ and $c_1,c_2$ are real numbers. This is usually easier than actually furnishing the matrix.

Comment: It can be especially easy because you can use the fact that you already know certain operations are linear: for example, differentiation is linear, multiplication by a fixed polynomial is linear, and a sum of linear functions is linear.

Comment: I did the proof you spoke of in the first part, but after that I'm asked to find the linear-trans matrix and I'm not sure about it since after "sending" $x^3$ as an argument I got $x^4$

Comment: OK, so you do need to find the matrix. Well, $\mathbb{P}_4$ (the codomain) has dimension $5$ and $\mathbb{P}_3$ (the domain) has dimension $4$, so your matrix will be $5 \times 4$.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I get it now sir.. I'll post my solution in 3 minutes, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ian could you view my solution, I have edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do your basis vectors go?

$L(1)= 1+4x\\
L(x) = (x + 4x^2) + (x - x^2) = 2x + 3x^2$

$L(P(x))=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\4&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix} P(x)$

Does this give you the idea?

Comment: I have written my solution in the edit, please review it, thanks!

Comment: Does your matrix in the edit take $1$ where it need to go?

Comment: Shouldn't L(1) be 5? I mean is the L(p)(x) = 1+4x+..., now if we take 1 it should be 1+4*1 = 5? or is the x on the other side a different x?

Comment: No... $x$ does not equal one.   We have a polynomial $p(x) = 1$ is not the same thing as $p(1).$  We transform $p(x)$ to a new polynomial.  $x$ is still $x.$

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KC7zk3E.jpg so here everything besides the p(x)=1 is correct, it should yiled L(1) = 1+4x thus giving the column [1 4 0 0 0]?

Comment: first colum is [1 4 0 0 0], not first row.